# Run multiple instance of a same script in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, puppeteer, child-process

I'm working on a website offering scraping with Puppeteer on NodeJS, so I decided to make a website using NodeJS and Express.

The scraping script must therefore be executed once a form has been completed.

The script must therefore be executed again for each new request without canceling the previous one. Hence I don't know how much script will be loaded in advance.

I think [PM2](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) can be a good idea but, I'm not sure if it meets my needs.

Or I could use [Node.js Cluster](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v16.x/docs/api/cluster.html), this would allow me to create a fork for each filled form.

Here is the tree structure of my project:

```
my-app/
├─ bin/
│  ├─ www
├─ node_modules/
├─ public/
│  ├─ images/
│  ├─ javascript/
│  │  ├─ scrapper.js
│  │  ├─ script.js
│  ├─ stylesheets/
├─ routes/
│  ├─ index.js
├─ views/
│  ├─ error.pug
│  ├─ index.pug
│  ├─ layout.pug
├─ app.json
├─ package-lock.json
├─ package.json
```

Comment: Using pm2 takes care of that for you and automatically create nodejs cluster for your script

Comment: @Icekid So it would be best to use pm2 directly? But from what I've seen, PM2 only runs from command line. I don't really see how to automate the creation process.

Comment: yeah its just like deploying multiple servers that all point to the same domain. it balances the load between all the scripts

Comment: So, if I understood. I use pm2 to launch different nodeJS servers that will allow me to make several requests. Is it right? 
And if I understand it I should run this command: pm2 start ./bin/www -i `Number of server I want`